# jquery mobile gallery show just first word of the alt description

Tags: jquery, image, gallery, bind, attr

I am using a great photo gallery called [jQuery Mobile Gallery](http://www.irinavelychko.com/tutorials/jquery-mobile-gallery) but have a problem.

If you put the text in alt property or title property by hand like this:

`alt="Picture 1"` works ok, but if the text is taken from database like this:

`alt= row['description']` it just take the text Picture, not "Picture 1" (`row['description']` has the correct value, tested).

so, for more complex description of the image I always get the first word;

This is the code:

```
$(function(){   

    function gonext() {
        var current = $('a.selectedimg');
        if (current.hasClass('last')) {
            if (current.hasClass('first')) {
                $('#nextbtn').button("disable");
                $('#prevbtn').button("disable");
            }else {
                var next = $('a.first')
            }
        } else {
            var next = current.next();
        }

        var src = next.find('img').attr("src");
        var alt = next.find('img').attr("alt");
        var title = next.find('img').attr("title");
        alert("gonext.title: "+ title);
        next.addClass('selectedimg');
        current.removeClass('selectedimg');
        $('#dialogcontent').empty().append('<a href="#gallerypage"><img src="' + src + '" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/></a>' );
        $('#dialoghead').empty().append('<center><h6>' + title + '</h6></center>' );

    } 

    function goprev() {
        var current = $('a.selectedimg');
        if (current.hasClass('first')) {
            if (current.hasClass('last')) {
                $('#nextbtn').button("disable");
                $('#prevbtn').button("disable");
            }else {
                var prev = $('a.last')
            }

        } else {
            var prev = current.prev();
        }
        var src = prev.find('img').attr("src");
        var alt = prev.find('img').attr("alt");
        var title = prev.find('img').attr("title");
        prev.addClass('selectedimg');
        current.removeClass('selectedimg');
        $('#dialogcontent').empty().append('<a href="#gallerypage"><img src="' + src + '" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/></a>' );
        $('#dialoghead').empty().append('<center><h6>' + title + '</h6></center>' );
    }

    $('.gallerycontent img').bind('tap',function(event, ui){
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
        var title = $(this).attr("title");


        alert("gallerycontent.title: "+title );

        $('#dialogcontent').empty().append('<a href="#gallerypage"><img src="' + src + '" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/></a>' );
        $('#dialoghead').empty().append('<center><h6>' + title + '</h6></center>' );
        $(this).parent().addClass('selectedimg');
    });

    $('#nextbtn').bind('tap',function(event, ui){
        gonext();
    });

    $('#imgshow').bind('swipeleft',function(event, ui){
        gonext();
    });

    $('#prevbtn').bind('tap',function(event, ui){
        goprev();
    });

    $('#imgshow').bind('swiperight',function(event, ui){
        goprev();
    });
});
```

Any idea why this occurs? or how to fix?

Thanks.

This is the code in php file (11/oct/2012):

```
                    $index = 1;
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        if ($index == 1) {
                            if ($n_reg == 1) {
                                echo "<a href=\"#imgshow\" data-transition=\"pop\" data-rel=\"dialog\" class=\"first last\" ><img src=" . $row['foto'] . " alt=" . $row['descripcion'] . " title=" . $row['descripcion'] . "/></a>"; 
                            } else {
                                echo "<a href=\"#imgshow\" data-transition=\"pop\" data-rel=\"dialog\" class=\"first\"><img src=" . $row['foto']  . " alt=" . $row['descripcion'] . " title=" . $row['descripcion'] . "/></a>";
                            }
                        } else if ($index == $n_reg) {
                            echo "<a href=\"#imgshow\" data-transition=\"pop\" data-rel=\"dialog\" class=\"last\"><img src=" . $row['foto'] ."  alt=" . $row['descripcion'] . " title=" . $row['descripcion'] . "/></a>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<a href=\"#imgshow\" data-transition=\"pop\" data-rel=\"dialog\" ><img src=" . $row['foto'] . " alt=" . $row['descripcion'] . " title=" . $row['descripcion'] . " /></a>";
                        }
                        $index++;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the backend code, I have to guess.  It looks like you are missing double quotes around the text that you want for the `alt` tag.

you have this:

```
alt=Picture 1
```

you want this:

```
alt="Picture 1"
```

Comment: If you post your backend code that generates this, we can help you get it sorted.